# node -v and nodejs -v gives me two different version numbers

Tags: node.js, version, upgrade, versions

Hi I have a node installation on my Linux machine.

When I run `node -v` command on the terminal, its show me `0.10.32`
And when I run `nodejs -v`, it shows me the same version. i.e `0.10.32`

Now I upgraded my node using the following commands:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Now when I run `node -v`, it shows me the versions as `0.12.7`
And when I run `nodejs -v`, it show me the version as `0.10.32`

I am a bit confused with this.

Why are they different, and why do we have node and nodejs, as two separate things?

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've probably installed node through the system's package manager to get the `nodejs` command, and installed the `node` command using `n`. In that case, they're two entirely different installs of the same thing.

Comment: It looks like a younger version ("nodejs") was established with the system package manager. Try to remove it by standard means of the OS (for example, in Ubuntu: sudo apt-get remove nodejs).

Comment: Thank you for replying. But which one should I keep `node` or `nodejs`?
I tried to remove `node`, and it says `Package 'node' is not installed, so not removed`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson How do I upgrade nodejs then? Can you help?

Comment: Now this is bugging me, I tried to upgrade `nodejs` by doing this `sudo apt-get install nodejs`. And it started upgrading. Now when I check the version using `nodejs -v`, its showing it as `0.10.40`. Before running the install command, it was at `0.10.32`. Why is it that it didn't upgrade to `0.12.7`(which is the latest version - as shown on nodejs.org). My `node` is already on `0.12.7`. Whats wrong with nodejs????

Comment: package managers tend to have outdated versions. you need to install it manually, from source or using nvm to get newer version.

Comment: @webduvet, so do I uninstall `nodejs`, and let `node` stay back there. B'coz my node shows me its already in version `0.12.7`. Also will uninstalling nodejs affect my already installed modules(I am not talking about the global packages/modules). Thanks :-)

Comment: well try if it works :) you should be fine, if not then you add symlink to your node

Answer (score 2):

Check your node location `which node`
then remove node

> rm -r path/node

Then link your nodejs with node

> sudo ln -s `which nodejs` /usr/bin/node